# Get Facebook app scoped user id LIKES

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I know you get a users "likes" from the graph api by doing

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/userid?fields=likes
```

However this only works with Real User Ids. What I don't understand is how is my app supposed to get the users "likes" if the App can't get the real User ID?

Originally I was testing this with my Facebook account and everything worked. But I'm now guessing this because I'm assigned as a developer to the App, I was get the Real User ID.

Comment: Ok this might be something to do with the access token... As if I use the access token generated by Graph Explorer it returns the Users Likes...
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/me/?access_token=ACCESSTOKEN&fields=likes. This would mean it's a permission problem? However I am requesting 'user_likes' when login in..

Comment: This was the issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45959306/getting-user-likes-an-user-events-app-review-process